# how i can reset all the field values inside a Div element using Jquery in my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have the following view:-

```
<div id = "partialWrapper">
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Answer", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "incrementanswer",
    OnSuccess = "removePartial"
}))

 {
     <div id = "returnedquestion">
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Answer here</legend> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-label"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-field"> 
             @Html.DropDownList("IsRight", String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsRight) 
        </div>  
    </fieldset> 
     <input type= "hidden" name = "questionid" value = @ViewBag.questionid>
     <input type= "hidden" name = "assessmentid" value = @ViewBag.assessmentid>
     <input type="submit" value="Add answer" />
 </div>
 }
 </div>
```

i want to clear all the data inside the fields so that the users can easily add new objects, i tried the following but these will remove the text and fields :-

```
function removePartial() {
    $("#partialWrapper").remove();
}
```

and

```
function removePartial() {
    $("#partialWrapper").empty();
}
```

**so is there a way to clear the text inside the all the fields within a Div without removing the fields themself.**
BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reseting the form:

```
$('#partialWrapper form')[0].reset();
```

Comment: +1 this is the ideal approach, as it will not *reset* `hidden fields`, which appears to be the OP's intent.